# Checking selected value of a react 'select' using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have checked the documentation and apparantly this is how you look at the selected value of a select (drop down combo box) using **Enzyme** :

```
let select = wrapper.find('select');
expect(select.props().value).toBe('SELECTED_VALUE');
```

This however is not what I get for **select.props().value**.

My **select.props().value** is a big json object which looks like some kind of component.

How do I get the value?

Answer (score 1):

OK I just had a bit of a look, and it seems like I have to write it like this :

```
let select = wrapper.find('select');
expect(select.props().value.target.value).toBe('SELECTED_VALUE');
```

This looks kinda ugly :/

Is there something better?

**UPDATE :**

OK, I realise now that I was being a bit silly. When I was submitting my change event I was actually submitting the component itself as the value. That is why value.target.value works for me. After realising my error it works normally again.

In short, yes, the correct way is :

```
let select = wrapper.find('select');
expect(select.props().value).toBe('SELECTED_VALUE');
```

Just make sure you know what you are sending in your change event.